# Configure better index choices for MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table with ~17M rows where I end up doing a lot of aggregation queries.

For this example lets say I have `index_on_b`, `index_on_c`, `compound_index_on_a_b`, `compound_index_on_a_c`

I try and run a query explain

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM table WHERE a = some_value AND b = other_value
```

And I find that the selected index is `index_on_b`, but when I use a query hint

```
SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM table USE INDEX(compound_index_on_a_b)
```

The query runs way way faster. Is there anything I can do in MySQL config to make MySQL choose the compound indexes first?

Comment: Please provide the actual `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.  There could be subtle things such as datatype inconsistencies getting in the way.  Also `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible routes you can take:

A) The index resolution process is when according to the optimizer all things are equal based on the order the indexes are created in. You could drop index_b and recreate it and check if the optimizer was in a scenario where it just thought they were the same.

Or

B) Use optimizer_search_depth (see https://mariadb.com/blog/setting-optimizer-search-depth-mysql). By altering this parameter you determine how much effort the optimizer is allowed to spend on a query plan, and it might come up with the much better solution of using the combined index.

Comment: What about index cardinality and updating this using analyse table?

Comment: @Shadow: How the cardinality is used is part of the optimizer process, and can as far as I know not be influenced. The analyze table only keeps it up to date (which is not a bad idea: It is best to have this information up to date).

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen thanks for the reply. I was able to find a bunch of options for tweaking the query plan selection algorithm, but I still can't figure out what is causing MySQL to choose index merge or larger indexes over the compound index

Comment: Despite being open source, which gives 100% insight in the optimizer algorithm, it is documented poorly, so that is a really hard question to answer. I also noticed this tendency to use non-optimal indexes in different scenarios. This is a continuous battle in pretty much all relational DBMS

Comment: "Index merge" is almost always slower than the appropriate compound index.

Comment: @BrianWheeler - what version are you running?  There were significant changes relating to `ANALYZE` beginning in 5.6.

Comment: @BrianWheeler - Your Question does not imply that it is picking "index merge", but your Comment does.  What gives?

Comment: @RickJames I'm probably just leaving out important details when I simplified the question to fit stackoverflow format. For some queries it uses an index merge and others it just picks a shitty index

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation:

If `a` has the same value throughout the table, then `INDEX(b)` is actually better than `INDEX(a,b)`.  This is because the former is smaller, hence faster to work with.  Note that both will return the same number of rows, even without further checking of `a`.

Please provide:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
SHOW INDEXES  -- to see cardinality
EXPLAIN SELECT
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't set the question up correctly but in this case `INDEX(a, b)` is certainly 100x faster (found through experimentation)